# How do I remove all licenses from a user using the AzureAD v2 Module?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft365

I need to remove all licenses from a user in Microsoft 365 using the AzureAD v2 Powershell Module (Not MSOnline or Microsoft.Graph).

I tried following the documentation for [Set-AzureADUserLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserlicense?view=azureadps-2.0), but it doesn't explain how to remove licenses using this cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$azureUser = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString <search-string>

$skuIds = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

foreach ($license in $azureUser.AssignedLicenses)
{
    $skuIds.Add($license.SkuId)
}

$licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$licenses.RemoveLicenses = $skuIds

Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $azureUser.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $licenses
```

How did I come to discover this?

Well first we find out through the documentation (or when trying to use the cmdlet) that the **AssignedLicenses** parameter takes an object of type **AssignedLicenses**. A cursory search doesn't find any page documenting this type, but we can see a clue in the documented example. The fully qualified type is **Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses**.

If we instantiate an object of this type into a Powershell session, we can inspect the members. We see that there is an **AddLicenses** property that takes a **System.Collections.Generic.List** of **AssignedLicense** objects. This is the property used in the example explaining how to add a license.

We also see a property called **RemoveLicenses** that takes a **System.Collections.Generic.List** of strings. We can make an educated guess that the strings need to be license SkuIds.

Now we have everything we need to know to start testing, and we can draw some insight from the documented example of adding a license! In my answer I instantiated an **AssignedLicenses** object, populated it's **RemoveLicenses** property with a generic list of license SkuIds, passed that into the cmdlet, and voila.